# Elastic beanstalk Rails - defaults to production environment even if I set staging environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, rails, computing-environment

I am trying to bring up a staging instance of rails applciation using elastic beanstalk. I followed the documentation and did the following :

```
eb init --environment staging
eb start --environment staging
```

After this, I checked that the .elasticbeanstalk/optionsettings still had 'production' as the environment. I manually updated this to staging, and tried the git aws.push command.

After sometime, everything was deployed, However, when I load the URL,  the application still seems to be using all the production configs and not the staging. Am I missing any step ?